# Why command get from a command line in TFS removes parallel projects?

Tags: tfs

I have 2 projects A and B.  They should remain in parallel directories.  I created 2 labels, one for project A, the other one for project B.

I use tf get by label for project A and then tf get by label for another project B.  For some reason tf get by label A deletes another project B and vise versa.

Checking out by Label from the Visual Studio Client looks fine – I can get both projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If label A contains only project A, and label B contains only project B, then when you ask TFS to do a get of `$/`, then it will ensure that your workspace matches what you requested, up to and including deleting items that exist locally that aren't part of label A.

If you're seeing differences in Visual Studio, that's probably because you're selecting `project A` and performing a get on the label A and `project B` and performing a get on label B.  This would mean that `project A` is at the changeset given by label A and `project B` is at the changeset given by project B.

On the other hand, when you perform a get of `$/` at a label spec, then you will get *only* the label spec.

If you want to match the behavior of Visual Studio, you can do a get of `project A` and `project B`:

```
tf get $/ProjectA /version:LA
tf get $/ProjectB /version:LB
```

Comment: I tried to implement the suggestion, thank you.
So my original label was <date>-<projectName>.
tf get /version:L<labelName> get the project but removes the other projects – thank you for explanation.
However, tf get $/<projectName> /version:L<labelName>  gives the error message:
TF14064: Could not find label <labelName>@$/<projectName>.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: The same note but with actiual code.
tf get /version:LRC-2013-03-21-A -works but delete other projects.
However,

tf get $/A  /version:LRC-2013-03-21-A gives the error:
TF14064: Could not find label RC-2013-03-21-@$/<FolderName>/A.

Comment: For some reason I needed to modify the suggested script to make it working.  So, what works:  tf get ProjectA /version:LA.  Also, in my case the command should be issued in the ROOT folder of ProjectA