# How to associate an Eclipse Workspace with TFS workspace?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am working with Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse Version 11.0.0.

I have several Eclipse workspaces and several TFS workspaces. Is it possible to associate a TFS workspace with an Eclipse workspace?
I see that mapping local folder does not work for this purpose – the workspace remains the same

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  In the recommended workflow, a single Eclipse workspace *does* map to a single TFS workspace, if you use the Import Wizard.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568707.aspx  Could you better describe the problem(s) you're having?

Comment: Yes, it does. But what if you have this mapping and you want to change it - in your workspace map to another TFS workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write them down.

I work on a project with a team that has this same issue. After a lot of digging it doesn't seem to be possible. It would have to be functionality in the TFS plugin also if I'm not mistaken. So until the TFS plugin is released with this ability of "mapping your mappings" so to speak, it's something you have to personally keep track of.

(Perhaps the TFS plugin for Luna will have this?)

Comment: http://help.teamprise.com/3.1/index.jsp?topic=/com.teamprise.help/plugindoc/gs_workspace_change.html

Comment: From teamprize: "When the Eclipse Workbench opens, the TFS workspace associated with that Eclipse workspace is activated."   My question is how to switch to another TFS workspace in the existent Eclipse workspace

Answer (score 14):

Team explorer - Pending changes - Actions - Switch workspace

[image: TFS - Switch workspace]