# Selenium Java Integration with Team Foundation Server

Tags: selenium, tfs

I am currently working on Selenium Automation using Java for my test Automation needs. I use TestNg for my reporting as of now.

No integration was done earlier with any tool for  reporting and I was manually updating the TestNg results in JIRA.

Visaul Studio Team Foundation Server has been introduced by the client recently. I would like to know the below in this regards.

1. How can we update the execution results on Selenium-TestNG in TFS?
2. Will we be able to run the Selenium scripts from TFS as we do from HP-ALM?
3. Since I use Selenium-Java, will it be a problem for any integration if possible with TFS. (Reason for asking is that I have heard that TFS uses C#)
4. Any possible methods how I can integrate these two systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very **broad** and requires lots of research and perhaps a proof of concept to verify that it suits your needs. I hope you're not looking for a code snippet to fix all your problems ;)

First, let's divide and conquer. You want TFS integration with Java. TFS doesn't care if you use Selenium or any other framework. Second, you want to read TestNG results into TFS. As it's possible, I'm [not sure it's a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232144/tfs-for-java-bad-idea) and maybe you should think about moving to C# and .NET for your testing.

So to answer your questions:

1. You can either [read xUnit results to TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerBuildExtensionsPowerToolDecemb), or [implement your own](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) `IReporter` and [read it with TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#add-test-results-to-a-test-run).
2. Running your scripts is simply [running Java with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233961/2470092).
3. Yes TFS is natively for C#, but there are extensions for Java, so integration is possible, though it's not as smooth as working with something native for your programming language.
4. TFS and Java can be integrated as explained above.

Comment: Thank you very much Moshisho.So is it possible only to read only xUnit results/ireporter. Is TestNg report not compatible for TFS API?

Comment: The report is only html, TFS needs a specific template to read the results. It's a trx file. So try looking for a converter from xUnit results to trx file.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/f90f1861-239c-48db-863c-050fa6a62d3a/how-to-publish-java-test-scripts-results-using-testng-and-maven-in-tfs?forum=tee