# How to run my selenium tests ( created using testng, maven ) from TFS

Tags: selenium, tfs

I am new to TFS, I have uploaded my Selenium test code to TFS,  and want to run the testng suite from TFS.  I tried all the procedures available online, but not succeeded.  If anyone could list out the steps involved, would be much helpfull to sort this out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Andy,

Thanks for the reply.

I use Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

For the steps involved you can refer to [Get started with Selenium testing in a CI pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium) or this blog: [Getting Started with Selenium Testing in a Continuous Integration Pipeline with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/01/27/getting-started-with-selenium-testing-in-a-continuous-integration-pipeline-with-visual-studio/).

If you are using the TFS2015 or later with vNext build system, you can refer to this link for detailed steps to [Build your Java app with Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/java-maven).

Also this thread for your reference: [Selenium Java Integration with Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912499/selenium-java-integration-with-team-foundation-server?rq=1)

Comment: @Mahe You can follow the steps mentioned in above links to run the test in TFS.