# TFS- Selenium java integration

Tags: java, selenium, tfs

I have written selenium tests in eclipse java. I have manual test cases in tfs. Is there a way to update automation test status in tfs thru java code

Comment: Is there...? Please search the documentation and/or search engines.

Answer (score 0):

About the TFS and java integration, take a look at below question:

> Microsoft provide a full, rich [TFS Plug-in for Eclipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=vsts) (called
>   **Team Explorer Everywhere**). This provides full source control, work item tracking, build, sharepoint, reports access etc into TFS from
>   Eclipse based IDE's. It's written in 100% Java and talks directly to
>   the web services exposed by TFS.
>
> *Source Link:
>   [TFS for Java - bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232144/tfs-for-java-bad-idea)*

More details about how to get the best out of TFS if you are a Java developer, checkout: Working with [Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)/TFS and Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=vsts)

---

If you want to link Java Test Automation with Microsoft Test Manager, TFS , Test Cases, which is not support for now, track this uservoice: [Enable Java Automated Test to execute from MTM and get the java test automation linked to manual test cases](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11386173-enable-java-automated-test-to-execute-from-mtm-and)

If you want to update automation test results/report in tfs, possibility duplicate of this question: [Selenium Java Integration with Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912499/selenium-java-integration-with-team-foundation-server) Please go through the details in the answer, which should be helpful for you.