# Execute Selenium java scripts from Release Definition in TFS 2015

Tags: java, selenium, tfs

We have a test suite automated in Selenium with Java using Maven.
Now we have TFS 2015 and we were able to use the Maven task to build the selenium project in Build Definition in TFS 2015.

I have seen several links which describe executing Selenium scripts in C# from TFS Release Definition on a remote machine, but I could not find any information on how the Selenium scripts developed in java can be triggered from TFS Release Definition.

We don't want to re-do the whole automation in C#.

So please can you help me to know how Selenium java scripts can be triggered from TFS 2015 and results can be copied back to the release definition?

Answer (score 0):

This should similar as this thread: [Selenium Java Integration with Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912499/selenium-java-integration-with-team-foundation-server)

> First, let's divide and conquer. You want TFS integration with Java,
>   TFS doesn't care if you use Selenium or another framework. Second, you
>   want to read TestNG results into TFS. As it's possible, I'm [not sure
>   it's a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232144/tfs-for-java-bad-idea) and maybe you should moving to C# and .NET in
>   your testing.
>
> So to answer your questions:
>
> 1. You can either [read xUnit results to TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerBuildExtensionsPowerToolDecemb), or [implement your own](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) `IReporter` and [read it with TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#add-test-results-to-a-test-run).
> 2. Running your scripts is simply [running Java with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233961/2470092).
> 3. Yes TFS is natively for C#, but there are extensions for Java, so integration is possible, though it's not as smooth as working with
>      something native for your programming language.
> 4. TFS and Java can be integrated as explained above.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have seen this thread which you have shared. It basically talks about  TFS Build Extensions which allow you to run Ant or Maven based builds on the Team Foundation Build server. But it does not talk about triggering Maven build for Selenium from TFS Release Definition task on to a remote machine. So in short with the Maven task we can build the Selenium code from the repository and copy the Selenium scripts to remote machine, but we are not able to find a task that will trigger the Selenium scripts on the remote machines or VM